# Apple Watch Remote notifications not calling didReceiveRemoteNotification method

Tags: xcode, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch

I have been seeing some really strange behavior from the Apple watch and I can't find any tutorials or SO questions that solve my problem.

I am trying to show a dynamic, long-look notification on the watch. When I send the APN out, the phone receives the notification immediately (phone screen doesn't light up or buzz, but if you check the lock screen, it is there). The watch doesn't receive the notification until a whole minute or so later and Xcode prints out "`(app name) took too long to show custom notification. Falling back to static`". But right now I don't even have anything in the didReceiveRemoteNotification method besides `completionHandler(.Custom)` in NotificationController (my subclass of WKUserNotificationInterfaceController). I seems as if didReceiveRemoteNotification never even gets called because it never hits the breakpoint I set.
The watch is receiving notifications from other apps correctly, so it has to be something wrong with my app (right?).

I have checked that the dynamic interface controller on the Storyboard's class is set to NotificationController correctly, have tried restarting both devices, and have been searching through posts for possible solutions for hours. What am I missing? Thank you in advance.

edit:
Also seems like the warning that the custom notification took too long only appears as soon as I interact with the notification on the phone. But only if I interact with it more than 30 seconds after the phone receives it.